# Can a function inside a list access the list's attributes in R?

Tags: r, list, function, reference

In the following example, a function inside a list should return the string `"The value currently is 42"`.

```
l <- list(
  param = 42,
  f = function() { paste("The value currently is", param) }
)
```

(example inspired by Mozilla's js-documentation of the keyword [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this))

Obviously calling `l$f()` fails because of `object 'param' not found`.

I tried inspecting objects available in the environment with `ls.str()` and `ls()`. The closest solution I came to was referencing the variable name the list is assigned to.

```
l <- list(
  param = 42,
  f = function() { paste("The value currently is", l$param) }
)
```

This of course is somewhat suboptimal, since the variable could be named anything.

Is there a way for the function inside `l` to refer to its neighboring attribute `param`? If not, is there some nested more involved solution that accomplishes a similar task?

Comment: Is there a specific use case you want to apply this to? This construct looks very strange to me and I can't really imagine what its use would be. Maybe an example would help me to figure out what kind of construct would achieve your goal.

Comment: @Julian_Hn A little hard to describe, but with a dozen or so attributes in a `list` I wanted to have a function inside the list that returns some useful information depending on the attribute's values (for example build some string representation of the list, get all numeric attributes that are negative, etc). I didn't want to create global functions that are passed lists just for this. I used the `this` approach quite a lot in JavaScript, though I suppose in R there are other paradigms for this type of issue.

Comment: Would that not be the typical example for OOP? So create a class with assigned functions and then you can apply these functions to each instance of the class and perform the desired actions on this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lst()` in the `tibble` package builds components sequentially. When defining a component, you can refer to components created earlier in the call.

```
l <- tibble::lst(
  param = 42,
  f = function() { paste("The value currently is", param) }
)

l$f()

# [1] "The value currently is 42"
```

The `param` value in `f` cannot be replaced simply by `l$param <- value` because it has been stored into an environment associated with `f`. You can use `assign()` and specify the `envir` argument to that environment and overwrite it.

```
assign("param", 10, envir = environment(l$f))

l$f()

# [1] "The value currently is 10"
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! Though there's probably no way to update the `param` value and have function `f` also use the updated value, right?

Comment: @FelixJassler It can be updated with `assign()`. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match.call` inside the function to capture the list's name from the subsetting call used to access the function. If you `eval` this symbol in the parent frame, you have an equivalent of a (dereferenced) `this`.

This gives the desired behaviour, as shown in the following reprex:

```r
l <- list(a = 1, 
          f = function() {
            mc <- match.call()
            this_sym <- as.list(as.list(mc)[[1]])[[2]]
            this <- eval(this_sym, envir =  parent.frame())
            cat("Value of ", as.character(this_sym), "$a is ", this$a, sep ="")
          })

l$f()
#> Value of l$a is 1

l$a <- 42

l$f()
#> Value of l$a is 42

new_list <- l

new_list$f()
#> Value of new_list$a is 42
```

However, this feels like it's trying to use a plain list to replicate the sort of object-oriented programming that can already be done much better with an R6 or S4 class.

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so one solution I came up with is having a function create the list object. This way I know what the variable name will be, though from my limited testing I can't quite be sure that there aren't any hidden bugs.

```
createList <- function() {
  l <- list(
    param = 42,
    f = function() { paste("The value currently is", l$param) }
  )

  return(l)
}

# name shadowing doesn't seem to be an issue
l <- createList()

# prints "The value currently is 42"
print(l$f())
```

EDIT: This does not work when `param` is modified.

```r
l <- createList()
l$f() # 42

l$param <- 0
l$f() # 42
```

EDIT: As in @Darren's solution, the value can be redefined inside the function using `assign`.

```r
l <- createList()

# param has to be updated at two locations
l$param <- 0
assign("param", 0, envir = environment(l$f))
```

At this point one might as well start working with classes.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of building a list you build a proto object it can be done easily.  (proto objects are environments with additional methods.)

```
library(proto)

p <- proto(param = 42, f = function(.) paste("The current value is", .$param))
p$f()
## [1] "The current value is 42"
```

To later change param use:

```
p$param <- 43
```

or create a child object which does not modify p but rather creates a new object which reuses the f method from its parent in a new object p2 with its own value of param.

```
p2 <- p$proto(param = 44)

p2$f()
## [1] "The current value is 44"
```

The above is the preferred way to do this but if you don't intend to generate child objects from p then this would work as well. It is the same except we use param rather than .$param .

```
p3 <- proto(param = 42, f = function(.) paste("The current value is", param))
p3$f()
## [1] "The current value is 42"
```